# Diagram of covariant and contravariant basis in a system of curvilinear coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, differential-topology

I want to double-check that I understand the following [diagram in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors):

[image]

We are dealing with curvilinear coordinates, $q^1, q^2, q^3.$

$e_1,e_2,e_3$ are tangential arrow vectors to the *coordinate curves* (in black)

$e^1, e^2, e^3$ are orthogonal to the *coordinate surfaces* defined by the intersecting coordinate curves.

The image in the lower left hand corner is the parallelogram construction using contravariant vectors to represent $\vec v.$

**And the question:**

> The image in the lower right hand corner is the representation of $\vec v$ through **stacks**? What are the small stacked-up squares like spread out decks of cards? Are we implying density?

In other words, I'm asking about the connection with this other diagram:

[image]